# get main menu items list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing a scenario where I need to get all items from main menu so i can use the same menu on a different place that don't have it, i only have access to front end, a js sheet and css.

This is the menu html: the nav is structured this way ( body.home header nav )

```
  <ul class="menu-principal">
        <li class="text1 "><a href="#" class="text1" target="">text1</a></li>   
        <li class="text2 "><a href="#" class="text2" target="">text2</a></li>       
        <li class="text3 "><a href="#" class="text3" target="">text3</a></li>       
        <li class="text4 "><a href="#" class="text4" target="">text4</a></li>                       
    </ul>
<script>
     $(".menu-principal > ul > li > a").each(function () {
        var children = $(this).next('ul').children();
        alert(children.length);
     });

 /*****************************/

  $("body header nav .menu-principal").each(function() {
      var children = $(this).children();
      alert(children.length);
   });

  /******************/
  $(".menu-principal").each(function() {
      var children = $(this).children();
      alert(children.length);
   }); 
</script>
```

all I need is to be able to fetch the menu list, due the menu is in several language when language is selected the fetch as well should get list in selected language.

The above is 3 attempts I have tried but not lucky.

Comment: Well, for starters, you've misspelled `script` as `scritp`.

Comment: i edited the script my bad when i wrote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> get all items from main menu so i can use the sme menu on a different
>   place that dont have it

If you want to use the same menu somewhere else, you can use `clone()`. Simply make a clone of the element and append it elsewhere.

```js
var menu = $('.menu-principal').clone();
$('body').append(menu);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu-principal">

        <li class="text1 "><a href="#" class="text1" target="">text1</a></li>

        <li class="text2 "><a href="#" class="text2" target="">text2</a></li>

        <li class="text3 "><a href="#" class="text3" target="">text3</a></li>

        <li class="text4 "><a href="#" class="text4" target="">text4</a></li>

    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

I modified your selector. It is able to access the text of anchor tag.

```js
$(".menu-principal > li > a").each(function () {
    console.log($(this).text())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu-principal">
        <li class="text1 "><a href="#" class="text1" target="">text1</a></li>
        <li class="text2 "><a href="#" class="text2" target="">text2</a></li>
        <li class="text3 "><a href="#" class="text3" target="">text3</a></li>
        <li class="text4 "><a href="#" class="text4" target="">text4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it did worked, but the links i cannot get it, is there a way i can get the menu list with the links

Comment: i append the result to a text but i have no url path for each menu list, how can i achive this

Comment: @walteralexander You can use `$(this).attr('href')` to get the href inside the `each` loop

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for:

```js
// .menu-principal is the <ul> so you don't want to look for a <ul>
// that is a child of it.
$(".menu-principal > li > a").each(function () {
  console.log(this.href);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu-principal">
  <li class="text1 "><a href="http://cnn.com" class="text1" target="">text1</a></li>
  <li class="text2 "><a href="http://fox.com" class="text2" target="">text2</a></li>
  <li class="text3 "><a href="http://cbs.com" class="text3" target="">text3</a></li>
  <li class="text4 "><a href="http://nbc.com" class="text4" target="">text4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i got the menu but not the links is there a way i can do this, or maybe is there my menu is structure is way i cant get the links

Comment: @walterexandet please explain what you mean by getting the links. My code does exactly that it gets the text of the links. What exactly do you need

Comment: for some reason i get text of each menu item, but i doent not have the path, example.          i do have text1 but no url path, i did saw your snippet with url paths but mine, doesnt will this be realted to my website been blocking this from me somehow

Comment: @walteralexander It's just a matter of asking for the `href` instead of the `textContent` of each `a` element once you have them. You didn't have any actual paths set up for your links, you only had `#`. I've added actual links and updated my answer to show how to get them.